# tcl : manipulating numbers bigger than 0xFFFFFFFF with `format`

Tags: tcl

I need to do some operation on MAC addresses, coded on 48 bits, but `format` truncates the results :

`format 0x%x 0x100000000 ;# --> 0x0`

Is it possible to do something for this, or must I adapt my code to use smaller numbers ?

Comment: what Tcl version are you using? In Tcl 8.5.11, 8.6.0 and 8.4.20 your code gives to me `0x100000000` and not `0x0`. Try to specify the size modifier, to avoid truncation: `format 0x%llx ...`, or to convert the `0xffffffff` value to wide integer by calling the `wide()` function on it: `... [expr ( wide(0xffffffff) + 1 ) ]`

Comment: I'm using 8.4.17.
And I have the same problem with `wide` or `format 0x%11x`

Comment: Oh sorry @MarcoPallante. You had the answer actually, you just made a typo : it's `format 0x%lx`.

Add your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry, @emmasculateur, the double lowercase el is 8.5 syntax. In 8.4 you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tcl 8.4 just give the size modifier `l` to the field specificator of `format`. This way, you tell `format` to interpret the value as (at least) 64-bit number (same size of `wide()`, which is machine dependent):

```
format 0x%lx 0x100000000
```

(Note that it is a lower case *el* letter, not the *one* digit.)

In Tcl 8.5 and later, integer math is done with arbitrary precision and the `ll` size modifier tells `format` to not truncate the value:

```
format 0x%llx 0x100000000
```

(Again, they are two lower case *el* letters, not two *one* digits.)